# Can't change encoding of freemarker template to UTF-8 in spring framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, encoding, freemarker

I can't change the encoding to UTF-8, even if I explicitly specify it. Page in browser always created with encoding ISO-8859-1 and my language symbols show as "???". If it important - i'm use IntelliJ IDEA.

It's problem with freemarker because when I change it to jsp, pages generate with encoding UTF-8.

I tried to change encoding with:

1. Check encoding in IDE
2. <#ftl encoding>
3. <#setting url_escaping_charset="UTF-8">
4. <#setting output_encoding="UTF-8">
5. specify `produces` parameter in @....Mapping annotations
6. Specify encoding in `FreeMarkerConfigurer`
7. Specify content type in `FreeMarkerResolver`
8. Specify encoding in `CharacterEncodingFilter`
9. Specify encoding in implementation of `Filter`
10. Specify content type in `FreeMarkerConfigurerFactory`

But nothing of it didn't give me a solution

[Result in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZQFw.jpg)

[Freemarker template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKn5v.jpg)

[Project in gitHub](https://vk.com/away.php?to=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FVakarine%2FencodingProblem)

Comment: This problem is most certainly outside the scope of FreeMarker. FreeMarker just writes its output to a `java.io.Writer`, and that's always UTF-16. It's the embedding framework/application that provides that `Writer`. As it will be a HTTP response in your case, at some later point the Servlet implementation will do the encoding, certainly to the charset set as the encoding of the `HttpServletResponse`. FreeMarker doesn't set that, as it's not dependent on Servlets. So it's a generic Servlet and/or Spring Web setting, not a FreeMarker one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution - when we implement WebMvcConfigurer and use registry.freemarker Spring configure freemarker himself and us beans FreemarkerViewResolver & Configurer 
did not affect anything.